# good or bad practice: Using imported JavaScript files to do most of the work for each page

Tags: javascript, import, architecture, multipage

If you've already built a multipage application, this question is really easy for you.

So I'm currently developing my first multi page website and I've run into a dilemma. So, I am trying to integrate JavaScript into each of my pages, but I'm not sure what to do and not to do. I've been told that putting the event listeners on the main JavaScript file for the given page is the best practice, but if I got that route, then I must add event listeners to each page if I need to implement the same features.

Adding on to event listeners, I will also be making many API requests. Would it be a good practice if I fetch in each individual controller? Or would it be a bad practice?

However, this way seems to be really future proof and will have much less repetition.

So here is the javascript file for my home page:

```
import { classes, element } from "./base";

// Add sidebar functionalities
import * as sidebarController from "./controllers/sidebarController";

// Add media post functionilities
import * as mediaController from "./controllers/mediaController";
```

Simple right? A bit too simple.

So, each of these imports includes functions that automatically add event listeners to the page.

Here is sidebarController:

```
import { classes, element } from "../base";

// MESSAGES
const scrollChatDown = (chat) => {
  chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
};

export const contactsScroll = (contacts, direction) => {
  const dir = ["left", "right"];
  const fn = [() => (contacts.scrollLeft -= 150), () => (contacts.scrollLeft += 150)];

  fn[dir.indexOf(direction)]();
};

// EVENT LISTENERS
// messages - There should be only one per page
if (element.sideMsg) {
  // Automatically scroll chat down
  scrollChatDown(element.sideMsgChat);

  // Chat scroll functionality
  element.sideMsg.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (e.target.matches(`${classes.sideMsgLeft}, ${classes.sideMsgLeft} *`)) {
      contactsScroll(element.sideMsgContacts, "left");
    } else if (e.target.matches(`${classes.sideMsgRight}, ${classes.sideMsgRight} *`)) {
      contactsScroll(element.sideMsgContacts, "right");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: If that *Sidebar* is part of 100% of your pages... why not? Otherwise you could import it without your Sidebar Template - And than you import that sidebar on the components where a sidebar is needed. I'm just worried to see too many *Chat* related stuff inside that *"Sidebar"* - have you thought about creating a Chat component? Sidebar should handle sidebar stuff only (expand, retract, import buttons, chats etc...). A Chat is a Chat. If a Chat needs to propagate events - using an Observer pattern you can tell Sidebar to listen to those changes - instead of mixing code.

Comment: So you're saying that the sidebar should listen to things, and call something like a `chatController` to perform the code? That's a good idea, but I feel like there would be too many imports, and it would get very confusing.

Comment: I remember so many times your exact thoughts. Let's not split code, it'll become confusing. Than a year later a client wanted some components reused and scattered in many places. I regretted my decisions - the project can become a copy/paste spaghetti nightmare if not wisely addressing the possible future uses and flexibility.